# 'Not valid archive' when using pg_restore

Tags: postgresql, pg

As someone who is very new to working with databases/SQL I'm having trouble setting up a dump from the database Qscored, which can be found at https://zenodo.org/record/4468361#.YgTTZ-7ML0p, the first dump (ab) is the one I've worked with. The downloaded file is of type `POSIX tar archive`. According to the README file, these are the commands to be run in a terminal window.

```
cat qscored_dump_25Jan2021ab > qscored_dump_25Jan2021.tar

psql -U postgres
```

When in a PostGreSQL user run

```
CREATE DATABASE qscoreddb WITH TEMPLATE=template0 ENCODING='UTF-8';
CREATE USER dbwala WITH PASSWORD 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE qscoreddb TO dbwala;
```

Then, in a new terminal window I run pg_restore according to

```
pg_restore -d qscoreddb -U postgres \path\to\qscoreddb_dump_Jan252021.tar
```

I then get the error message

```
pg_restore: error: input file does not appear to be a valid archive
```

Does anyone know how I might be able to solve this problem or does it mean there are problems in the original file?

I'm using PostGreSQL 14 with a Mac Monterey 12.2.

Comment: The readme says to concatenate *all* the files into one.  All you did is rename one of the files, the hard way.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming at all, but about how to use resources from some web site.

Comment: @jjanes Thank you very much. I didn't realize that all of the dumps were to be concatenated into one tar file. But concatinating all dumps works fine!